# iOS: Large UIAlertController ActionSheet bouncing while scrolling and not showing line separators

Tags: ios, swift, uiactionsheet, uialertcontroller

I have **two questions** with a **long** action sheet including 20 options (larger than the screen height):

**Question 1**. How to disable vertical bounces while scrolling?

**Question 2**. How to show the line separators while scrolling to the bottom?

Missing line separators of **Question 2**:

[image]

I am using Xcode 6.4 and iOS 8.4 simulator. The two issues also exist with my iPad running the same code on iOS 9.0.2.

I have created an action sheet using `UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet`. I have added 20 options in the action sheet using `addAction`.

My **ViewController**.swift is as below:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(50, 60, 200, 20))
    button.setTitle("Press", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "btnPressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(button)
}

func btnPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    let controller = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

    for item in 1...20 {
        controller.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Option \(item)", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { action in
        }))
    }
    controller.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))

    presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

For **Question 1**:

Is there any bounces property that can be set like in UITableView: `tableView.bounces = false` to prevent long action sheets from vertical bounces while scrolling?

For **Question 2**:

This is different from "[UIActionSheet is not showing separator on the last item on iOS 7 GM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18790868/uiactionsheet-is-not-showing-separator-on-the-last-item-on-ios-7-gm)", which uses the deprecated `UIActionSheet` in stead of `UIAlertController` with `UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet`. Adding the "Cancel" option to the action sheet does not seem to be a solution.

If I add a title or message to the action sheet or remove the "Cancel" option from it, bottom line separators are still missing.

Is it possible to show these missing lines?

Comment: Looks like a bug. Submit a bug report to Apple. Include a simple app that demonstrates the problem. Of course Apple won't be fixing any issues with iOS 8. It will be fixed (if not done already) in iOS 9.1.x or later.

Comment: OK. I've submitted a bug report to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to disable scrolling in a view (and all of its subviews), this code should work just fine for you.

```
- (void)disableBouncingInView:(UIView *)view {
    for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
        if ([subview respondsToSelector:@selector(setBounces:)]) {
            UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView *)subview;
            [scrollView setBounces:NO];
        }

        [self disableBouncingInView];
    }
}
```

and call it like this:

```
[self disableBouncingInView:myAlertController.view];
```

**EDIT**:

I just saw that this question was tagged with `swift`, so here's that same idea in swift:

```
func disableBouncingInView(view : UIView) {
    for subview in view.subviews as [UIView]  {
        if let scrollView = subview as? UIScrollView {
            scrollView.bounces = false
        }

        disableBouncingInView(subview)
    }
}
```

and called like this:

```
        disableBouncingInView(myAlertController.view)
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution to **Question 1**. When I use `disableBouncingInView(controller)` with Xcode 7.1, I got this: Cannot convert value of type 'UIAlertController' to expected argument type 'UIView'. So I modified the code as `disableBouncingInView(controller.view)` and then there is no more bouncing.

Comment: Yep, sorry for that mistake. I'll fix it now!

Comment: I just found Apple's guidelines in **UIAlertController Class Reference**: "The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified."  [https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/) So I probably can't submit an app with this solution to App Store.

Comment: Fortunately, this solution does not modify the view in any way, it only interacts with it. If you were adding a subview or modifying a cell in the tableview then there'd be a conflict, but interacting with (or disabling certain cosmetic interactions) shouldn't be an issue.