# Xamarin iOS 8 - UIActionSheet missing separator lines (Persistent error)

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have tried all the solutions suggested here, for this question, but none of them works. Could the solution for Xamarin be a different one?

This is what I have tried, based on this answer here:

[Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18790868/uiactionsheet-is-not-showing-separator-on-the-last-item-on-ios-7-gm)

```
actionSheetAlert = new UIActionSheet("Select Make",null,null,null,null);

foreach(string item in allData)
{
    actionSheetAlert.AddButton(item);
}       

actionSheetAlert.AddButton("Cancel");

//Add Cancel button

actionSheetAlert.CancelButtonIndex = actionSheetAlert.ButtonCount-1;

actionSheetAlert.ShowInView(tableView);
```

Adding a cancel button with an empty string(instead of null) as others have also suggested , during the initialization of the actionsheet also doesn't solve it for me. I still have missing separator lines towards the end.

See screen shot below.

[image]

Comment: Is this a screenshot from the simulator or from a device?

Comment: Hi @Sven-MichaelStübe . This is from an iPhone. The same thing happens on an iPad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the UIActionSheet is obsolete for iOS 8, I tried going with the recommended UIAlertController but the result was the same because I wanted to use the `UIAlertControllerStyle` as the `UIActionSheet`. I eventually decided to go with a normal `UITableView` to display my list of data.

My lists were too long for an action sheet anyway and needed scrolling, so a tableview seemed logical here.